# Angular 4 routing: nested child views: "URL segment not found"

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

> **edit** it works when removing the "name" from my nested outlet AND removing the "outlet" property from the routes module. Is it mandatory to have an unnamed outlet before using named ones?

The following RouterMOdule config is in place:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

  // Public area: login (default)
  { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthAutoRedirectService],
    children: [
      { path: '',       outlet: 'active-box', component: LoginComponent }
    ]
  },

  // Secure area
  { path: 'secure', component: SecureAreaComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: { roles: ['user'] },
    children: [

      // Dashboard (default)
      { path: '',             outlet: 'main-content', component: DashboardComponent },

      // Resolutions
      { path: 'resolutions',  outlet: 'main-content', component: ResolutionsComponent },

      // Documents
      { path: 'documents',  outlet: 'main-content', component: DocumentsComponent },
    ]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports:[
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports:[
    RouterModule    // configured router module
  ]
})
```

- `router-outlet` : displays the logon page OR the secure area whereabouts
  | - `router-outlet name="main-content"` displays the selected page in the secure area

  - `localhost:4200/` properly serves the login page
  - `localhost:4200/secure` properly serves the secure area, showing the "dashboard" as main page

the problem arises when trying to access an other child of the secure area:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'secure/documents'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'secure/documents'
```

What could be the cause?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this explains that:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14830

> You must have the outlet with the name primary on a template (if you don't specify the name it will be primary by default). Named outlets are auxiliary.

Outlet with name is an "auxiliary" outlet. Needs at least a "primary" (aka "unnamed") outlet.